# Firebase Functions npm install is always stuck

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to host a node app using firebase functions. Now everything works fine. 
I run the command

```
firebase init functions
```

Then I follow the steps. (Firebase tools are correctly installed).

Then after some steps it asks me to

**Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes**

I say yes and then it does something at at a point it is stuck.

This is the screenshot

[image]

The solutions I tried.

I tried running the following command on functions folder

```
npm install --verbose
```

It doesn't displays any clue as well here is the screenshot.

[image]

I also tried reinstalling node, reinstalling the whole firebase cli. I cleared npm cache and tried. Nothing work so far.

Here is my **package.json** file.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Could you please provide some information about your environment setup such as OS and versions of node, npm and firebase-tools.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, 64 bit OS and the latest node 11.6.0 I also tried with 10.15.0 lts nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you tried using node 10.15.0 and 11.6.0, but neither of them is currently supported by Google Cloud Functions.

The currently supported versions are [Node.js 6](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-6-runtime) (6.14.0) and [Node.js 8](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime) (8.14.0), so I suggest you use one of them to setup your project's runtime (just bear in mind that the Node.js 8 runtime is still beta). You can check out complete and updated info about Cloud Functions supported runtimes [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes).

So what I suggest you try is using one of these node versions to install firebase-tools and them setup your project. For example, for Node.js 6.14.0:

```
# install node.js 6.14.0 version (if you don't have it already)
$ nvm install 6.14.0

# use node.js 6.14.0 version
$ nvm use 6.14.0

# install firebase cli
$ npm install -g firebase-tools

# login with your google credentials
$ firebase login

# init your project
$ firebase init functions
```

**Important:** if your project's directory already has a `node_modules` folder, delete it **before** running `firesbase init functions`.

Comment: Now after this I am facing another issue, can you please help me on this

Comment: Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967986/firebase-function-not-working-failed-to-emulate-app

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Node.js on your development machine is bad. Do this:

```
nvm install 8.6.1
nvm alias default 8.6.1
```

Then nail Firebase Functions Node.js runtime to version 8 by adding this to your `package.json` file inside your `functions` folder:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

Comment: Although updating node might perhaps help. Configuring to use version 8 of node is itself not a solution. At the time of writing, version 6 is still default and should also work.

Comment: Node 8.0.0 will throw up errors eventually. 8.6.1 is the solution. ...I've run into this myself. I can't think of a reason not to use Node8 runtime?

Comment: I am using windows, nvm is not available for windows. Any other solution

Comment: Its not working I tried, using nvm windows, and did as you said, but 8.6.1 is not available version it is saying. I tried with 8.15.0 but the issue remains the same it is stuck

Comment: I tried installing the dependencies separately it is the firebase-admin that is not getting installed.