# Firebase Function not Working - Failed to emulate app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to serve my firebase cloud functions, I get this message. 
[image]

My firebase.json file is here

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites":[{
        "source":"/hello",
        "function":"app"
    }]
  }
}
```

The index.js file inside function folder

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.get('/hello', (request, response)=>{
        response.send("Hello Working");
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And here is the debug log that shows the error I am getting.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\iambe\AppData\Local\Temp;\tmp-47763kzGi6NyBhNP.zip'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:1169:18)
    at Object.writeFileTo (C:\Users\iambe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\adm-zip\util\utils.js:111:20)
    at Object.writeZip (C:\Users\iambe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\adm-zip\adm-zip.js:534:20)
    at client.generateUploadUrl.then.then (C:\Users\iambe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\@google-cloud\functions-emulator\src\cli\controller.js:168:13)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
[warn] !  functions: Failed to emulate app
[info] i  functions: No HTTPS functions found. Use firebase functions:shell if you would like to emulate other types of functions.
```

If anyone faced the similar issue and solved? I tried searching everywhere nothing helped so far.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now, I know it's related to node version because I use nvm-windows to manage node version on different projects, however, I don't know why it's not working right now.. did you solve it?

Comment: No it is not related to the node version, but it is related to your temp directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution. The problem here is not with the node version but with the temp directory location. 
In the error message we can see that it is saying that **no such file or directory** and after this we can see the path where it is checking for the file.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\iambe\AppData\Local\Temp
```

So the problem here is we have a temp directory configuration for nodejs as well. But there is some issue and node is getting confused because of the settings of temp directory of the system. And it is not looking at nodejs temp directory but it is looking at windows temp directory.

This is the explanation of the problem. Now let me tell you the solution. What I did is I removed the TEMP variable from the environment variables.

[image]

And you are done. Hope this will help.

But I am not sure why this is happening because in some computers with this temp directory as well no problem. But in some computers we have this problem. If anyone having the exact reason, let me know.